Epson java adk unable to claim acces to printer inside docker container
this is fragment of my code:
try {
            ptr.open("WIFI");
            log.info("printer status open {}", ptr.getState());

        } catch (JposException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This device has not been registered, or cannot use.", e);
        }

        try {
            // Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            // Then the device is disabled from other applications.
            ptr.claim(3000);
            log.info("printer status claim {}", ptr.getState());
        } catch (JposException e) {
            try {
                log.info("printer status claim error {}", ptr.getState());
                ptr.close();
            } catch (JposException closeException) {
                // Log the close exception if needed
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Fails to get the exclusive access for the device.", e);
        }

on my host machine everything working correct, but inside docker container I have following error
printer-service-1  | 2024-07-16 19:29:37.872  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.gdma.printer.service.PrinterService  : printer status open 2
printer-service-1  | 2024-07-16 19:29:37.873  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.gdma.printer.service.PrinterService  : printer status claim error 2
printer-service-1  | 2024-07-16 19:29:37.878 ERROR 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fails to get the exclusive access for the device.] with root cause
printer-service-1  | 
printer-service-1  | jpos.JposException: PortHandler Win32 error.
printer-service-1  |    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001T1.pntr.CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.createJposException(CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.java:138) ~[epsonjpos.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001T1.pntr.CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.createJposException(CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.java:99) ~[epsonjpos.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001T1.pntr.CommonPrinterService.openPort(CommonPrinterService.java:3409) ~[epsonjpos.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001T1.pntr.CommonPrinterService.claim(CommonPrinterService.java:3189) ~[epsonjpos.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at jpos.BaseJposControl.claim(Unknown Source) ~[jpos1141.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at com.gdma.printer.service.PrinterService.printMessage(PrinterService.java:37) ~[classes!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at com.gdma.printer.controller.PrinterController.printMessage(PrinterController.java:22) ~[classes!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
printer-service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
printer-service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
printer-service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.31.jar!/:5.3.31]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.83.jar!/:na]
printer-service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
printer-service-1  | 

So I am guessing this ptr.open("WIFI"); is working, so my printer is visible for container. Inside container am able to execute telnet command and print some stuff from keyboard. I am thinking that maybe problem is with some privileges. This is my docker compose:
services:
    printer-service:
      hostname: printer-svc
      image: image/image:printer-service
      privileged: true
      ports:
        - "8082:8080"
      logging:
        driver: syslog

